# DrRacket EOPL Scheme output

Tags: scheme, racket

I am working through the EOPL Scheme exercises using DrRacket in Windows 7.  When I switch from #lang racket to #lang eopl, the output from the definitions pane no longer shows up in the interaction pane. To be clear, as trivial example, running

```
    #lang racket
    4
```

produces

```
    4
    >
```

as you would expect. But running

```
    #lang eopl
    4
```

produces only

```
    >
```

Is there anything I can do to change this behavior or is there another pane I should be looking at for output?  I can, of course, evaluate expressions in the interaction pane and see the output, but this is tedious when I have multiple expressions I want to evaluate multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `#lang eopl` uses [`#%plain-module-begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html?q=module-begin&q=apply&q=transpose#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._~23~25plain-module-begin%29%29), which does not print results, instead of [`#%module-begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html?q=module-begin&q=apply&q=transpose#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._~23~25module-begin%29%29), which does print results.

For a quick way to switch, create the following file with the following contents:

`eopl-printing.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(require (except-in eopl #%module-begin))
(provide (all-from-out eopl))
(provide #%module-begin)
```

Then use this as the language in another file:

```
#lang s-exp "eopl-printing.rkt"
1
2
3
```

produces in my DrRacket:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.4.6 [3m].
Language: s-exp "eopl-printing.rkt" [custom].
1
2
3
>
```

CAVEAT: If `eopl` was hiding the results for a reason, then you may get some spurious output, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Less intrusive solution.  I've switched to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround: print the value in the definitions pane, so it'll show up in the interactions pane. And use `newline` to separate lines:

```
(write 4)
(newline)
(write 2)

> 4
> 2
```

Of course, it'll be tedious if you want to display many values, but it's an improvement.

Comment: Tedious, yes but it produces legible output if I intersperse `(display "\n")` between the multiple values. Thanks, I'll use this for now.

Comment: Don't use `display` to print values; use `print` instead. Use `(newline)` or `(display "\n")` for newlines.

Comment: @RyanCulpepper I agree that using `(newline)` is a better idea, but `print` is not available in `#lang eopl`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ah, you're right. Then `write` would be the next best choice. The problem with `display` as a substitute for `print` is that it erases useful distinctions, and its behavior on compound data, like a list of strings, is just unhelpful, IMO.

Comment: @RyanCulpepper fair enough :) I updated my answer with your suggestions.