# Racket exn:fail? unbound

Tags: unit-testing, exception, module, scheme, racket

I've been using the following language definition file, `eopl-printing.rkt`,

```
#lang racket
    (require (except-in eopl #%module-begin))
    (provide (all-from-out eopl))
    (provide #%module-begin)
```

as suggested in [DrRacket EOPL Scheme output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638024/drracket-eopl-scheme-output). All has being going well, except when I try to invoke an exn function as in:

```
#lang s-exp "eopl-printing.rkt"
(require rackunit)
(check-exn
   exn:fail?
   (lambda ()
     (error 'hi "there")))
```

Instead of the test passing successfully as expected, I get a  "exn:fail?: unbound identifier ..." message.  I've read the documentation on modules and tried various ways to try to re-expose the Racket exn definitions but without any luck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `eopl-printing.rkt` file defines a language that only includes the bindings from the `eopl` library plus `#%module-begin` from `racket` but nothing else.

But you can still easily import `racket` bindings in any file written in the `eopl-printing.rkt` language:

```
#lang s-exp "eopl-printing.rkt"
(require rackunit)
(require racket)
(check-exn
   exn:fail?
   (lambda ()
     (error 'hi "there")))
```

Alternatively, you can have your `eopl-printing.rkt` language provide the additional `racket` forms that you want:

```
#lang racket
(require (except-in eopl #%module-begin))
(provide (all-from-out eopl))
(provide #%module-begin exn:fail? error)
```

Or just re-provide everything in `racket`:

```
#lang racket
(require (except-in eopl #%module-begin))
(provide (all-from-out eopl))
(provide (all-from-out racket))
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.  Do the first and third options run the risk of racket overriding eopl in the case where there are name conflicts?

Comment: Possibly. I ran the `eopl` test suite and didn't get any problems though. `eopl` mostly just re-provides stuff from `racket` anyways. And it looks like it is pretty good about redefining things, ie `eopl:printf` and `eopl:error`

Comment: Actually, scratch the last comment. I think [`all-from-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=all-from-out#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._all-from-out%29%29) does the right thing. There would be an error if there were conflicts.